# How to develop elm behind proxy

Tags: elm

Is it possible to self host elm packages like gems or nuggets?

The team already agreed to use it, but with our proxy we cant install packages.

thank you for the support

Comment: You could probably run [the package server](https://github.com/elm/package.elm-lang.org) locally and just set up your `hosts` file to point `packages.elm-lang.org` to it.

Comment: I am not in the office now, but will try it tomorrow
Thanks for the quick reply :)

Comment: This is also a little problem, we cant host haskell either :/

Answer (score 1):

What you can do is to clone the library your are looking for in the elm package manager cache.

However, I don't know how you will be able to manage to create the `version.dat` file.

Maybe copy it from another computer?

```
~/.elm$ tree -L 5
.
└── 0.19.0
    └── package
        ├── ContaSystemer
        │   └── elm-menu
        │       └── 1.0.2
        ├── elm
        │   ├── browser
        │   │   └── 1.0.1
        │   ├── bytes
        │   │   └── 1.0.7
        │   ├── core
        │   │   └── 1.0.2
        │   ├── file
        │   │   └── 1.0.1
        │   ├── html
        │   │   └── 1.0.0
        │   ├── http
        │   │   └── 2.0.0
        │   ├── json
        │   │   └── 1.1.2
        │   ├── parser
        │   │   └── 1.1.0
        │   ├── random
        │   │   └── 1.0.0
        │   ├── regex
        │   │   └── 1.0.0
        │   ├── time
        │   │   └── 1.0.0
        │   ├── url
        │   │   └── 1.0.0
        │   └── virtual-dom
        │       └── 1.0.0
        ├── elm-community
        │   ├── list-extra
        │   │   └── 8.1.0
        │   └── string-extra
        │       └── 4.0.0
        ├── elm-explorations
        │   └── test
        │       └── 1.0.0
        ├── goilluminate
        │   └── elm-fancy-daterangepicker
        │       └── 4.0.0
        ├── justinmimbs
        │   └── date
        │       └── 3.1.2
        ├── NoRedInk
        │   └── elm-json-decode-pipeline
        │       └── 1.0.0
        ├── rtfeldman
        │   ├── elm-hex
        │   │   └── 1.0.0
        │   └── elm-iso8601-date-strings
        │       └── 1.1.2
        ├── Skinney
        │   └── murmur3
        │       └── 2.0.7
        ├── terezka
        │   └── yaml
        │       └── 1.0.0
        ├── truqu
        │   └── elm-base64
        │       └── 2.0.4
        └── versions.dat
```